# How to deselect option on selecting option of another select in react

Tags: html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

I have an Antd React component like this:

```
class MyApp extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      select1="",
      select2="",
    }
  }
  deselectSelect(e){
    this.setState({ select1: e.target.value });
    this.setState({ select2: "" }); 
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Select
          placeholder="select first val"
          onChange={this.deselectSelect}
          value={this.state.select1} />
        <Select
          placeholder="select 2nd val"
          value={this.state.select2} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

What I want is when you an option from 1st you should deselect any value present in select 2. In my code, I am able to unselect the second select's value but the place placeholder is not coming back which was present initially when the page loaded. I think Antd (Library I am using in react for styling components) is setting the value as an empty string in 2nd select rather than deselecting the present value.

Comment: what is `Select`? which library?

Comment: antd is a react library just like react-bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `select2: ""` to `select2: undefined` on `deselectSelect`.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the `antd` API before, but I think this should work:

You might need to blur the selects in order for the placeholders to show up. Here's what I would try:

```
class MyApp extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      select1: "",
      select2: "",
    }
  }
  deselectSelect(e){
    this.setState({
      select1: e.target.value,
      select2: ""
    ), () => {
      this.sel2Ref.blur();  //runs **after** the above setState has finished
    }};
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Select
          placeholder="select first val"
          onChange={this.deselectSelect}
          value={this.state.select1} />
        <Select
          ref={(el) => this.sel2Ref = el}  //add a reference for DOM stuff later
          placeholder="select 2nd val"
          value={this.state.select2} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I added a `ref` prop to your 2nd select so that I can do DOM stuff later. When we do `deselectSelect()`, we use the callback function of `setState()` which runs *after* the new state has been updated (in this case, the selects get reset to `""`) in which we do a `blur()` on the second select. This should unfocus it making the placeholder appear again.

Few issues in your code:

1. You initialize the state incorrectly. Use `select1: ""` instead of `select1= ""`.
2. This is not an issue per se (because of batching), but you don't need to call `setState()` twice. Just call it one and set both your variables there instead of one at a time.

Comment: I don't know what to add in DOM stuff. I am getting that el not defined. Obviouls because i have not defined it but I am not able to under stand your ref syntax also as I am new to react and es6. Can you help me out by expanding your code and explanation.

Comment: P.S. Its select1="" in my real code. here i did a typo

Comment: @DadyByte i made one too. Missed a >. Try again

Comment: see, i am able to set  empty string('') as value of select. Your code is also doing the same. Thanks to you i now know I have to add something in onBlur which will  happen after setting state. But even with your code i don't know how to deselect the selected value which is seperate from setting empty string as value.